# Sorting the response object based on the attributes in the response

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, comparator

I have a request DTO with few input params.
I will be invoking a REST GET method in order to get a response. My response object has nearly 70 attributes and will be getting it in the JSON format.

I have a parameter in the request params called "sortBy" where I will be mentioning any attribute value of response based on which the response objects are to be sorted.

Request DTO :
{
bookBranch,
sortBy,
bookLocation
}

Response Json Object:
bookNo,
bookName,
bookIssueDate,
bookPrice  etc (other Book specific attributes)
}

So, Here if I give the bookBranch and bookLocation as input, I will receive the list of all books and its related attriutes list of that branch and location.

Is there a way to sort the list of books based on all the attributes of response object with the value given in the request params

Please help me how can I sort the response objects in case of all using java streams.

Thanks

I have defined a comparator just like below

public static final Map<String, Comparator> myMap=
Map.of("bookno", Comparator.comparing(ResponseDTO::getBookNo), "bookname", Comparator.comparing(ResponseDTO::getBookName),
"bookprice", Comparator.comparing(ResponseDTO::getBookPrice), "dateofissue", Comparator.comparing(ResponseDTO::getDateOfIssue));

and I am checking the value from the request

if (requestDto.getSortBy() != null && myMap.containsKey(dto.getSortBy().toLowerCase())) {

return ResponseList.stream().sorted(myMap.get(dto.getSortBy().toLowerCase()))                                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}

The above map takes only 10 entries at a time. What if My response json object has nearly 70 attributes?
This would be tedious to maintain 7 maps and do this check in all 7 maps .
Is there an alternate way to handle this scenario

Comment: Can you include your code segments to the question?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Please make an [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74599457/edit) - share a **simplified** (no need to expose 70 properties) incoming JSON, expected sorted result, employee-POJO, and your attempt to address the problem.